# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent

Tags: java, android, android-permission

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em Android para efectuar chamada telefónica. 
Dá-me a seguinte excepção:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxx cmp=com.android.server.telecom/.components.UserCallActivity } from ProcessRecord{1a0df5b 9112:pt.ipp.estg.broadcastapp/u0a265} (pid=9112, uid=10265) with revoked permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE

Esta ocorre quando entra no if e passa a linha do StartActivity do seguinte bloco de código:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edtNumTel = findViewById(R.id.edt_numero_telefone);
        btnFazerChamada = findViewById(R.id.btn_fazer_chamada);
        btnFazerChamada.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
               it.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+edtNumTel.getText().toString()));
               if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startActivity(it);
                 return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Adicionei a permissão no AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

E o seguinte bloco de código na Activity Main:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 1:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissao aceite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que o `if` está com a seguinte condição: "Se o app não tiver permissão para realizar chamadas, então, realize uma chamada."

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    startActivity(it);
    return;
}
```

Altere o trecho acima para:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    startActivity(it);
}
else {
    /* Exibe a tela para o usuário dar a permissão. */
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        NomeDeSuaActivity.this,
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
        REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Substitua o método `onRequestPermissionsResult` dessa forma:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissao aceite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Ps.:** Crie a constate REQUEST_CODE. Dessa forma `private static final Integer REQUEST_CODE = 1`

Comment: Não me reconhece o REQUEST_CODE

Comment: Penso que o REQUEST_CODE seja uma variável que esteja inicializada em algum lugar da activity.

Comment: Sim, você deve criar uma variável do tipo inteiro e armazenar um código nela. [Números Mágicos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_m%C3%A1gico_(inform%C3%A1tica)).